# Compare two files in python, ignoring headers

Tags: python, file

I wrote a quick python script to compare the files in two directories and delete any duplicates found. I've run into an issue however where some of my images, after having backed them up on the cloud, seem to have additional header information that wasn't in the original file which is causing the file comparison to fail.

Is there a way to compare files while ignoring header information (in this case the culprit file was a JPG however I foresee myself running the script on other file types too).

Help much appreciated.

If it's useful, I use SHA512 hash-comparison to determine file duplication (with an exiting strategy if the first x bytes produce differing hashes).

Comment: If you are worried about headers, why not start the pointer at the end of the file and stop when you reach the length of the shorter file?

Comment: You can handle the `.jpg` files in a different way. First check if the resolutions match, then compare two images using `cv2` and see if the difference is 0 for all the pixels.

Comment: You could use [exiftool](https://exiftool.org/) to (non-destructively) discard the header and send the remaining data to stdout ([see here for more details](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/51036)).

Comment: @Cresht If the shorter file has some metadata then it could generate false negatives from time-to-time

Comment: @swamp That's great for images. I wonder if there's a way to reliably do it for all file types? I was hoping there was a library that could do it for me, but I could even store the start/end bytes for the "data" portion of each file type in a json and use that in the script to selectively read these segments out for comparison